# Merge multidimesional and associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge two given Arrays into a new one:

First array:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>; Array
        (
            [label] => Please Choose
            [value] => default
        )

)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [label] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013 - 3.299 €
    [value] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013
)
```

I want to generate an arrays which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Please Choose
            [value] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013 - 3.299 €
            [value] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013
        )

)
```

I tried to merge the arrays:

```
array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Please Choose
            [value] => default
        )

    [label] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013 - 3.299 €
    [value] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013
)
```

What is the appropriate function for this use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you pass in the 2nd array inside another array you should get the desired output

```
array_merge($array1,array(1 => $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
array_merge($array1,array($array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the second array to the first one like this

If $array1 is

```
Array
  (
    [0] =>; Array
    (
        [label] => Please Choose
        [value] => default
    )

  );
```

and $array2 is

```
Array  
  (
     [label] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013 - 3.299 €
     [value] => 14.09.2013 - 27.09.2013
  );
```

then you can make $array2 a part of $array1 using

```
$array1[] = $array2;
```

This will cause $array2 to be a new item in $array1.